# PECL_HTTP http_parse_headers exact implementation

Tags: php

I am writting a class which communicates with a server through sockets and sends HTTP request.

I am using http_parse_headers function from pecl_http, but I didn't install it, so I've written a workaround. There are many on the documentation page. They all returns the HTTP status code as well (as a status key, or a 0 key). What I would like to know: does the *original* function returns it somehow? I would like to clone the functionality, so if anyone has this extension installed, the *original* function can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php), the only possible return values are:

- An array (containing the parsed headers)
- or `FALSE` (on failure).

Unless the HTTP status code is sent along with the headers, you won't be able to retrieve it by using the `http_parse_headers()` function.

If however the status code is sent along in the headers, it may look like this:

```
"HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"
```

It is therefore just a matter of interpretation (in the function you actually use) whether the status will be properly parsed and listed in the array of results or not.

In any case you can refer to [this function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php#112986) that was posted on php.net, which mimicks the behaviour of `http_parse_headers()` but which returns the HTTP status as the first key.

Comment: I've read the documentation and the examples. Let's say, I pass the HTTP StatusLine as well. I would like to know whether it is an undocumented feature and I GET the status as well, or it is just the commenter's bad concept of cloning functionality?

Comment: http_response_code won't work, as the communication itself is done through socket

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already thought about your points. I would like to exactly clone the function in the extension, because if I don't, it will mess up with the extension installed. If the status line/status code is NOT returned in the original function than the authors of those comments made a really big mistake, as their code won't run the same way in other environments, and it is a bad concept.

Comment: It seems so. I honestly cannot say for sure, as i have never used `http_parse_headers()`.

Comment: Well, I think this is enough for me to think, that the answer is no. I just needed someone else's thoughts about this. :) Thanks

Comment: If its important to you, setup PECL in a test environment and run a quick check.

Comment: This is what I don't want. :) I can get the status from the plain http response, then it is not a problem for me. If I found that it won't work properly, I will fix it, but I think there is a bigger chance of the first case.